# Is there a way i can shorten my switch statements

Tags: c++, oop

So Im editing a game off 3d tiktactoe and the switch statements are super long and i know there's a way to shorten it but i don't know how to go about it. the switch statements basically switch between turns of the player and the computer and they are tied to the spots on the board. here's the code:

```
bool D3Board::square_choose(bool player_Choice, int selection){

if(player_Choice)
    {
   // player turn 
    switch(selection)
    {
        case 1:
        {
            return square1.player_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 2:
        {
            return square2.player_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 3:{
            return square3.player_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 4:{
            return square4.player_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 5:{
            return square5.player_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 6:{
            return square6.player_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 7:{
            return square7.player_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 8:{
            return square8.player_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 9:{
            return square9.player_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 10:{
            return squareA1.player_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 11:{
            return squareA2.player_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 12:{
            return squareA3.player_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 13:{
            return squareA4.player_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 14:{
            return squareA5.player_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 15:{
            return squareA6.player_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 16:{
            return squareA7.player_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 17:{
            return squareA8.player_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 18:{
            return squareA9.player_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 19:{
            return squareB1.player_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 20:{
            return squareB2.player_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 21:{
            return squareB3.player_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 22:{
            return squareB4.player_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 23:{
            return squareB5.player_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 24:{
            return squareB6.player_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 25:{
            return squareB7.player_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 26:{
            return squareB8.player_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 27:{
            return squareB9.player_Choice();
            break;
        }
        default:
        {
            return 0;   
        }
    }
}
else{
    switch(selection)
    {
        case 1:{
            return square1.comp_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 2:{
            return square2.comp_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 3:{
            return square3.comp_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 4:{
            return square4.comp_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 5:{
            return square5.comp_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 6:{
            return square6.comp_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 7:{
            return square7.comp_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 8:{
            return square8.comp_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 9:{
            return square9.comp_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 10:{
            return squareA1.comp_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 11:{
            return squareA2.comp_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 12:{
            return squareA3.comp_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 13:{
            return squareA4.comp_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 14:{
            return squareA5.comp_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 15:{
            return squareA6.comp_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 16:{
            return squareA7.comp_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 17:{
            return squareA8.comp_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 18:{
            return squareA9.comp_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 19:{
            return squareB1.comp_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 20:{
            return squareB2.comp_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 21:{
            return squareB3.comp_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 22:{
            return squareB4.comp_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 23:{
            return squareB5.comp_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 24:{
            return squareB6.comp_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 25:{
            return squareB7.comp_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 26:{
            return squareB8.comp_Choice();
            break;
        }
        case 27:{
            return squareB9.comp_Choice();
            break;
        }
        default:{
            return 0;
        }
        
    }
}
```

}

Comment: At very first: You don't need to `break` if you `return` before anyway (break won't be reached!)...

Comment: Yes, you can delete all `break`.

Comment: make `square<N>` into an array/vector then you can just do `square[selection]`

Comment: If you *can* change the data structure, then pack all the `square`s into a `std::array` (if size is fixed) or `std::vector` (variable size), then you can access by index: `squares[selection]` (you need a sentinel for index 0 then) or `squares[selection - 1]` if you want to get along without sentinel.

Comment: Correction: `switch` statement is static anyway, so fixed size, so `std::array`...

Answer (score 3):

Place the `squareXY` in a container such that their index corresponds to the case label, then

```
if(player_Choice) {
     return squares[selection].player_Choice();
} else {
     return squares[selection].comp_Choice();
}
```

If the `squareXY` must be stored elsewhere for some reason, then `squares` can store pointers to the actual instances (-> `return squares[selection]->player_Choice()`).

---

In general (probably not in this particular case) a `std::unordered_map` or `std::map` can come in handy. For example when the lookup is not based on a contiguous unsigned integer. Just be aware of the tradeoff in memory and time complexity for look up (`std::map` stores a bit more than only the elements and has `O(logn)` lookup compared to `O(n)` with a simple array).

Comment: Smart pointers likely are wrong (`squareXY`  >`.`<)... Indices seem to be contiguous, so a simple array/vector of pointers should suffice as well (or if there are only small gaps, they might retain null pointers), and is more effcient (`O(1)` access vs. `O(log(n))`).

Comment: @Aconcagua right. tried to fix it a bit

Comment: Hope I'm not getting pedantic – but if we consider that every value stored in a `std::map` yet requires two pointers, then – depending on size of squares as well as size and number of gaps – we actually *might* not even have to trade ;)

Comment: @Aconcagua I like pedantics ;). And I didnt consider that. Though it is still a trade, just the turning point is more in favor of the array than I thought. Actually, I should remove the suggestion (tbh initially I was just too lazy to check if OPs selection is contiguous ;)

Comment: Or just rephrase it so that it gets a *general* suggestion, something like `In general, though not in your case, if there are large gaps then...` (but not *exactly* like that, don't like it...) – it might still be a good alternative in *other* use cases...

Answer (score 2):

While staying with `switch` you can remove in each case whatever is after `return`. It won't be executed anyway.

But it looks like your code could use an appropriatly filled array and then replace all of the `switch` with

```
return ArrayOfSquares[selection].playerChoice();
```

As the answer by not a number made me aware (credits), I should point out that you'd probably want to init the array[0] specially and you might still need an `if` for higher values.

Comment: Sole answer to hint to the now potentially necessary range check...

Answer (score 1):

Yes indeed, and very easily.

Store all your squares into an array and call the instance method directly by indexing over it. Your code would simplify to.

```
if(player_choice)
    return squares[selection].player_choice();
else
    return squares[selection].comp_choice();
```

Comment: Should i store the array as a method into my class?

Comment: @galapagos Arrays *cannot* be methods... You mean *member*. And yes, you should, at least if all those squares have been before, but *likely* even if not. Side note: *Method* is not among C++ wording at all, correct C++ terminology (following the standard) actually is *member function*...

Answer (score 1):

One major improvement you could do in your design is to avoid having independent `square` and prefer create a vector (or an array, or a map) of squares. That will allow you to access the squares with an index.

```
std::vector<MySquare> squares;
squares.push_back(MySquare());
squares.push_back(MySquare());
squares.push_back(MySquare());
...

// Later on, in your switch statement:
square[2].player_Choice();
square[45].player_Choice();
```

Comment: `std::vector<MySquare> squares(27);` would avoid 27 `squares.push_back(MySquare());`...

Comment: And as the number of squares is fixed anyway (otherwise a `switch` statement wouldn't have been possible at all), `std::array<MySquare, 27>` would be preferrable...

Answer (score 0):

Or to make this even shorter and a lot more readable and beginner friendly:

First put your methods in an array:

```
using fptr = bool(Square::*)()const;
static constexpr fptr F[2] = {&Square::comp_Choice,&Square::player_Choice};
```

Then have some array for your squares somewhere:

```
Square squares[27];
```

And now it gets as beautiful as this:

```
bool square_choose(bool p, int i)
{
    // no need for comments here, it's obvious
    return (squares[i].*(F[p?1:0]))();
}
```

Comment: @Aconcagua there is no negation, it is just a `(int)p`

Comment: And to clarify (it seems I have to clarify this), please don't do this. This is horrible advice if you're not planning to commit it the last day before leaving the company.

Comment: @Aconcagua yes, as I said, don't do this. It's horrible.

Comment: @Aconcagua Except for the ternary I totally agree with you. This answer wasn't supposed to be taken serious. But for the ternay, why do you think they're evil?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239159/discussion-between-aconcagua-and-stefan-riedel).

Comment: Moved to chat, deleted my comments here – I think we're deviating from the actual question/answer and aren't really contributing to any more...

Comment: `std::invoke(F[playerChoice?1:0], squares[selection]);` would be more beginner friendly... Method pointer syntax is not beginner friendly. (and use more explicit names, `F`, `p`  and `i` are no meaning :-/)